# how to handle errors of error handling system?

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

I've been working on developing a java web service. In this project I have an error handling system. My problem is what to do if the error handling system itself throws an exception(e.g. FileNotFoundExcption for the log file). Should it be swallowed? or Should it be sent to user or something else.

_new information_________

In my older prjects when ever an exception is thrown. 1-system catch the exception. 2a- system return an appropriate message to the user. 2b- System logs the exception with it's whole stack trace.this way the end user can inform the admin and admin sends me the error log. my question is what if the system can't log the exception. in the past i would have send a second message to the user to inform the system admin about this. I'm wondering if this is the right choice.

---

Any kind of information is appreciated.

Comment: You can give yourself a few levels of recovery. For example, 1) Can't find the log file, try to recreate it, 2) Still can't write to the log file, send a message, 3) If I'm sending a message, try to place log into a database table as well in case one of them fails.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelMarkidis. BTW, why do you implement your own logging system? Why don't you use one of standard loggers? There is a number of stable and mature enough logging libraries for Java, see https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-java-logging-frameworks/

Comment: @VinceEmigh you're right. to be more specific, any kind of exception that happens during the exception handling process. the situation i provided was just an example.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis. tank you. actually this is what i'm doing right now. to be more specific. in the system when ever an exception is thrown. 1-system catch the exception. 2a- system return an appropriate message to the user. 2b- System logs the exception with it's whole stack trace.this way the end user can inform the admin and admin sends me the error log.  my question is what if the system can't log the exception. in the past i would have send a second message to the user to inform the system admin about this. I'm wondering if this is the right choice

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev it's a really simple logging system implemented with 3 classes.  i didn't want to further complicate the project and add an external dependency and i wanted it to be as light as possible.   also as far as i'm informed those system can throw exceptions too. thank you for the link

Answer (score 1):

It depends. 
To catch or throw an exception, it all depends on the context in which exception occurs.

To answer your question If there is something that can be done with an exception, go ahead.

Comment: I agree, it depends on your bussiness needs and context. E.g. if end-user should be notified about fact that some file is missing then you can rethrow same exception or some more generic one, like your custom ConfigurationException("Configuration file not found")

Comment: @nike.laos actually this is what I've been doing till now. my last projects in such a situation send a message to the user that something bad happened and the system admin should be informed about it and the admin would inform me (the developer). i was wondering if there's a better way. tank you.